# Bidirectional rules in GNU make, without circular dependency error?

Tags: gnu-make

How can I avoid a `Circular ... dependency dropped` error from GNU make when defining a pair of bidirectional rules?

This is in a pandoc-based workflow where the input and output are (theoretically) bijective. I may generate a LaTeX file from Markdown, update the LaTeX directly, and later wish to convert back to Markdown.

If the output file already exists, it should be overwritten.

```
%.tex: %.md
    pandoc --from markdown --to latex --output $@ $<

%.md: %.tex
    pandoc --from tex --to markdown --output $@ $<
```

Comment: What is this supposed to mean? If both `foo.a` and `foo.b` exist, what is `make foo.a foo.b` supposed to do?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  make implements a DAG: directed _acyclic_ graph.  It's not possible for two targets to depend on each other.  If it were, how should make decide which one to build first, if neither one existed?  And how should it decide which one was out of date, if both existed?

Comment: I am using this in a pandoc workflow where I may wish to convert back and forth between different formats at different times. I have updated the example with clarification.

Comment: I'd like to do something like this as well. Direction picked through timestamp - update older from newer. Maybe invoking make recursively once for each direction, and make sure they get the same (newer) timestamp on build (or rather "sync").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realised there is a very simple solution: just remove the dependency from one (or both) of the rules, handle the extension within the rule, and then build with the `-B` flag.

Assuming there is one primary direction and one is less important or for debugging, the dependency can be removed from the less important rule.

`make -B foo.md`

```
%.tex: %.md
    pandoc --from markdown --to latex --output $@ $<

%.md:
    pandoc --from tex --to markdown --output $@ $(basename $@).tex
```

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is turn off one or the other rule, depending on what you wanted to build.  For example something like:

```
ifeq (,$(filter %.tex,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
%.md: %.tex
        pandoc --from tex --to markdown --output $@ $<
else
%.tex: %.md
        pandoc --from markdown --to latex --output $@ $<
endif
```